# How to properly escape a range in VBA/excel

Tags: excel, vba

I've this block of code that follows.  I'm struggling with the formula and properly trying to concatenate the range and escape (double double quotes?) the range properly.

```
Worksheets(ws_name).Range("B" & (row + 1)).Formula = "=COUNTIF(""B2:B"" & row, "">0"")"
```

I've searched and searched but cannot find my problem!

```
Dim ws_name
Dim row As Long
For Each ws_name In Worksheet_array
    If (ws_name <> "") Then
        Debug.Print ws_name
        row = Worksheets(ws_name).Range("B" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
        Worksheets(ws_name).Range("B" & (row + 1)).Formula = "=COUNTIF(""B2:B"" & row, "">0"")"
    End If
Next ws_name
```

Answer (score 3):

Try,

```
Worksheets(ws_name).Range("B" & (row + 1)).Formula = "=COUNTIF(B2:B" & row & ", "">0"")"
```

Comment: ++ Beat me to it :)

Comment: Thanks!... a bit counter-intuitive, but I get it

Comment: @JimfromPrinceton You want that `B2:B` portion to NOT have double quotes around it in the formula that will be written to the worksheet. So there is no need to get tangled up in escaping them as they just shouldn't be there. `=Countif("B2:B10", ">0")` would throw an error.